# Why does C++20 std::condition_variable not support std::stop_token?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, c++20

In C++20 Standard library [`std::condition_variable_any::wait()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable_any/wait) family support `std::stop_token` for generalized thread cancellation, but `std::condition_variable` does not.

[P0660R10 Stop Token and Joining Thread, Rev 10](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0660r10.pdf) says:

> New in R6
>
> - User `condition_variable_any` instead of `consition_variable` to avoid all possible races, deadlocks, and unintended undefined behavior.

I think that the following code safely emulates `condition_variable::wait()` with `stop_token` cancellation. What am I missing? Is there subtle edge case?

```cpp
template<class Lock, class Predicate>
bool cv_wait_with_stoken(
  std::condition_variable& cv, Lock& lock, std::stop_token stoken, Predicate pred)
{
  std::stop_callback callback{ stoken, [&cv]{ cv.notify_all(); } };
  while (!stoken.stop_requested()) {
    if (pred())
      return true;
    cv.wait(lock);
  }
  return pred();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a race condition.

In general with a condition variable, you must hold the mutex for some period **between** modifying the guarded state (usually a variable) and signaling the condition variable.  If you do not, you can miss a signal.

Making your state an atomic variable does not avoid that problem.

The wait code for a cv first checks the state.  If it fails, it then atomically drops the lock and waits on a signal.

If your stop token is set in that gap after it is checked, but before it waits, then the stop token calls notify all, that notify all won't be picked up by the condition variable.

The `cv.notify_all()` would have to be preceded by getting that lock.  And that opens up a whole can of worms.

Do not use this code, it will probably break horribly due to double locking or a a myriad of other things, but in theory it looks like:

```
bool cv_wait_with_stoken(
  std::condition_variable& cv,
  Lock& lock,
  std::stop_token stoken,
  Predicate pred
) {
  std::stop_callback callback{ stoken, [&cv]{
    lock.lock();
    lock.unlock();
    cv.notify_all();
  } };
  while (!stoken.stop_requested()) {
    if (pred())
      return true;
    cv.wait(lock);
  }
  return pred();
}
```

it may be possible to `try_lock` there, I would have to do a lot of hard proof work.

Comment: Do you intend to write that `lock.lock()` -> `cv.notify_all()` -> `lock.unlock()` ordering in stop_callback lambda? Anyway `std::condition_variable` accepts only `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` as Lockable, so such stop_callback may cause deadlock if a thread call [`request_stop()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/stop_source/request_stop) holds lock of the mutex.

Comment: @yohjp I made the can of worms warning more explicit.  The lock needs only be held at some point between the state changing and the notify; usually you'd also guard the variable.  But lock/unlock is enough to avoid a race, as the wait code holds the lock while checking the state and then atomically unlocks and waits for signals.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Good stuff. I added `if (lock.owns_lock()) return;` so that it doesn't double-lock when stop had already been request before construction of the callback. I have another concern though. Stop callbacks [run on the requesting thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread/request_stop#:~:text=will%20be%20invoked,is%20issued%20on). This means that `lock` is now shared across threads, but it isn't usually thread-safe. Assuming `unique_lock` wouldn't it be required to spell it more like so: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ktSz4YF2qk/ ?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - arrr make it more like https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fFK5qdrWMm/ to avoid deadlocks when indeed the function is entered when `stop_requested()` already returns true. I'd love to move the initial check outside the callback altogether, but that opens up another race condition where `stop_requested()` becomes true **right** after our initial check and **before** the check during `stop_callback` construction.  It's easy to make the presence of an - _unrelated_ - lock lull you into a false sense of security.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a `std::unique_lock`, pass a `std::mutex`.

The `std::condition_variable` only accepts `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&`, so there is no need to use template parameters for it.

```cpp
/**
 * @pre The #mutex is not locked. 
 */
template<class Predicate>
bool cv_wait_with_stoken(
  std::condition_variable& cv, std::mutex& mutex, std::stop_token stoken, Predicate pred)
{
  std::stop_callback callback{stoken, [&cv, &mutex] {
    { /// This locking is necessary to make sure the subsequent
      /// notify_all() is not lost in region X.
      std::lock_guard l(mutex);
    }
    cv.notify_all();
  }};
  std::unique_lock lock(mutex);
  while (!stoken.stop_requested()) {
    // Region X begins
    if (pred())
      return true;
    // Region X ends
    cv.wait(lock);
  }
  return pred();
}
```