# ThreadSanitizer: double lock of a mutex with std::jthread

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20

GCC thread sanitizer reports "double lock of a mutex" warning with code below:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>
#include <stop_token>
#include <thread>

template<typename Rep, typename Period>
void sleep_for(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& d, const std::stop_token& token)
{
    std::mutex mutex;

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ mutex };

    std::condition_variable_any().wait_for(lock, token, d, [&token]
    {
        return false;
    });
}

int main()
{
    std::jthread watch_dog_thread([](std::stop_token token)
    {
        sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(std::chrono::seconds(3)), token);
    });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    return 0;
}
```

GCC sanitizer output:

```
==================
    WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: double lock of a mutex (pid=6767)
    #0 pthread_mutex_lock ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:4250 (libtsan.so.0+0x53908)
    #1 __gthread_mutex_lock /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits/gthr-default.h:749 (MyAppTest+0x83c54)
    #2 std::mutex::lock() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_mutex.h:100 (MyAppTest+0x83fd2)
    #3 std::lock_guard<std::mutex>::lock_guard(std::mutex&) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_mutex.h:229 (MyAppTest+0x86974)
    #4 std::_V2::condition_variable_any::notify_all() /usr/include/c++/11/condition_variable:299 (MyAppTest+0x857f6)
    #5 operator() /usr/include/c++/11/condition_variable:404 (MyAppTest+0x2d9556)
    #6 _S_execute /usr/include/c++/11/stop_token:638 (MyAppTest+0x2d9d19)
    #7 std::stop_token::_Stop_cb::_M_run() /usr/include/c++/11/stop_token:148 (MyAppTest+0x849fd)
    #8 std::stop_token::_Stop_state_t::_M_request_stop() /usr/include/c++/11/stop_token:256 (MyAppTest+0x84d2a)
    #9 std::stop_source::request_stop() const /usr/include/c++/11/stop_token:536 (MyAppTest+0x8550c)
    #10 std::jthread::request_stop() /usr/include/c++/11/thread:201 (MyAppTest+0x856a6)
    #11 std::jthread::~jthread() /usr/include/c++/11/thread:129 (MyAppTest+0x8555b)
    #12 main /home/def/repos/MyApp/Tests/main.cpp:38 (MyAppTest+0x2d90c1)

Location is heap block of size 56 at 0x7b1000002000 allocated by thread T1:
    #0 operator new(unsigned long) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_new_delete.cpp:64 (libtsan.so.0+0x8f542)
    #1 __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::mutex, std::allocator<std::mutex>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) /usr/include/c++/11/ext/new_allocator.h:121 (MyAppTest+0x8b350)
    #2 std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::mutex, std::allocator<std::mutex>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/allocator.h:173 (MyAppTest+0x8af4f)
    #3 std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::mutex, std::allocator<std::mutex>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::mutex, std::allocator<std::mutex>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/alloc_traits.h:460 (MyAppTest+0x8af4f)
    #4 std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::mutex, std::allocator<std::mutex>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > > std::__allocate_guarded<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::mutex, std::allocator<std::mutex>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::mutex, std::allocator<std::mutex>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/allocated_ptr.h:97 (MyAppTest+0x8a96e)
    #5 std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<std::mutex, std::allocator<std::mutex>>(std::mutex*&, std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::mutex> >) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:648 (MyAppTest+0x8a1d9)
    #6 std::__shared_ptr<std::mutex, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::mutex>>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::mutex> >) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1337 (MyAppTest+0x8996e)
    #7 std::shared_ptr<std::mutex>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::mutex>>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::mutex> >) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/shared_ptr.h:409 (MyAppTest+0x88b8d)
    #8 std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> std::allocate_shared<std::mutex, std::allocator<std::mutex>>(std::allocator<std::mutex> const&) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/shared_ptr.h:861 (MyAppTest+0x87c56)
    #9 std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> std::make_shared<std::mutex>() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/shared_ptr.h:877 (MyAppTest+0x8688f)
    #10 std::_V2::condition_variable_any::condition_variable_any() /usr/include/c++/11/condition_variable:283 (MyAppTest+0x85763)
    #11 sleep_for<long int, std::ratio<1> > /home/def/repos/MyApp/Tests/main.cpp:21 (MyAppTest+0x2d91c0)
    #12 operator() /home/def/repos/MyApp/Tests/main.cpp:32 (MyAppTest+0x2d9016)
    #13 __invoke_impl<void, main()::<lambda(std::stop_token)>, std::stop_token> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:61 (MyAppTest+0x2da0db)
    #14 __invoke<main()::<lambda(std::stop_token)>, std::stop_token> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:96 (MyAppTest+0x2d9fd2)
    #15 _M_invoke<0, 1> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:253 (MyAppTest+0x2d9ede)
    #16 operator() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:260 (MyAppTest+0x2d9e6a)
    #17 _M_run /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:211 (MyAppTest+0x2d9e20)
    #18 <null> <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xda6b3)

Mutex M51 (0x7b1000002010) created at:
    #0 pthread_mutex_lock ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:4250 (libtsan.so.0+0x53908)
    #1 __gthread_mutex_lock /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits/gthr-default.h:749 (MyAppTest+0x83c54)
    #2 std::mutex::lock() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_mutex.h:100 (MyAppTest+0x83fd2)
    #3 std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::lock() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_lock.h:139 (MyAppTest+0x87e19)
    #4 std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::unique_lock(std::mutex&) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_lock.h:69 (MyAppTest+0x86c78)
    #5 wait_until<std::unique_lock<std::mutex>, std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> >, (anonymous namespace)::sleep_for<long int, std::ratio<1> >(const std::chrono::duration<long int>&, const std::stop_token&)::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/condition_variable:410 (MyAppTest+0x2d9642)
    #6 wait_for<std::unique_lock<std::mutex>, long int, std::ratio<1>, (anonymous namespace)::sleep_for<long int, std::ratio<1> >(const std::chrono::duration<long int>&, const std::stop_token&)::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/condition_variable:435 (MyAppTest+0x2d93ef)
    #7 sleep_for<long int, std::ratio<1> > /home/def/repos/MyApp/Tests/main.cpp:21 (MyAppTest+0x2d9204)
    #8 operator() /home/def/repos/MyApp/Tests/main.cpp:32 (MyAppTest+0x2d9016)
    #9 __invoke_impl<void, main()::<lambda(std::stop_token)>, std::stop_token> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:61 (MyAppTest+0x2da0db)
    #10 __invoke<main()::<lambda(std::stop_token)>, std::stop_token> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:96 (MyAppTest+0x2d9fd2)
    #11 _M_invoke<0, 1> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:253 (MyAppTest+0x2d9ede)
    #12 operator() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:260 (MyAppTest+0x2d9e6a)
    #13 _M_run /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:211 (MyAppTest+0x2d9e20)
    #14 <null> <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xda6b3)

Thread T1 (tid=6769, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:969 (libtsan.so.0+0x605f8)
    #1 std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xda989)
    #2 _S_create<main()::<lambda(std::stop_token)> > /usr/include/c++/11/thread:217 (MyAppTest+0x2d94c0)
    #3 jthread<main()::<lambda(std::stop_token)> > /usr/include/c++/11/thread:118 (MyAppTest+0x2d9301)
    #4 main /home/def/repos/MyApp/Tests/main.cpp:33 (MyAppTest+0x2d908a)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: double lock of a mutex /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits/gthr-default.h:749 in __gthread_mutex_lock
==================
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: lock-order-inversion (potential deadlock) (pid=6767)
Cycle in lock order graph: M48 (0x7fa6e2e9ece0) => M51 (0x7b1000002010) => M48

Mutex M51 acquired here while holding mutex M48 in thread T1:
    #0 pthread_mutex_lock ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:4250 (libtsan.so.0+0x53908)
    #1 __gthread_mutex_lock /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits/gthr-default.h:749 (MyAppTest+0x83c54)
    #2 std::mutex::lock() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_mutex.h:100 (MyAppTest+0x83fd2)
    #3 std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::lock() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_lock.h:139 (MyAppTest+0x87e19)
    #4 std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::unique_lock(std::mutex&) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_lock.h:69 (MyAppTest+0x86c78)
    #5 wait_until<std::unique_lock<std::mutex>, std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> >, (anonymous namespace)::sleep_for<long int, std::ratio<1> >(const std::chrono::duration<long int>&, const std::stop_token&)::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/condition_variable:410 (MyAppTest+0x2d9642)
    #6 wait_for<std::unique_lock<std::mutex>, long int, std::ratio<1>, (anonymous namespace)::sleep_for<long int, std::ratio<1> >(const std::chrono::duration<long int>&, const std::stop_token&)::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/condition_variable:435 (MyAppTest+0x2d93ef)
    #7 sleep_for<long int, std::ratio<1> > /home/def/repos/MyApp/Tests/main.cpp:21 (MyAppTest+0x2d9204)
    #8 operator() /home/def/repos/MyApp/Tests/main.cpp:32 (MyAppTest+0x2d9016)
    #9 __invoke_impl<void, main()::<lambda(std::stop_token)>, std::stop_token> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:61 (MyAppTest+0x2da0db)
    #10 __invoke<main()::<lambda(std::stop_token)>, std::stop_token> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:96 (MyAppTest+0x2d9fd2)
    #11 _M_invoke<0, 1> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:253 (MyAppTest+0x2d9ede)
    #12 operator() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:260 (MyAppTest+0x2d9e6a)
    #13 _M_run /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:211 (MyAppTest+0x2d9e20)
    #14 <null> <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xda6b3)

    Hint: use TSAN_OPTIONS=second_deadlock_stack=1 to get more informative warning message

Mutex M48 acquired here while holding mutex M51 in thread T1:
    #0 pthread_mutex_lock ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:4250 (libtsan.so.0+0x53908)
    #1 __gthread_mutex_lock /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits/gthr-default.h:749 (MyAppTest+0x83c54)
    #2 std::mutex::lock() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_mutex.h:100 (MyAppTest+0x83fd2)
    #3 std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::lock() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_lock.h:139 (MyAppTest+0x87e19)
    #4 std::_V2::condition_variable_any::_Unlock<std::unique_lock<std::mutex> >::~_Unlock() /usr/include/c++/11/condition_variable:272 (MyAppTest+0x888a5)
    #5 wait_until<std::unique_lock<std::mutex>, std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> >, (anonymous namespace)::sleep_for<long int, std::ratio<1> >(const std::chrono::duration<long int>&, const std::stop_token&)::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/condition_variable:419 (MyAppTest+0x2d9708)
    #6 wait_for<std::unique_lock<std::mutex>, long int, std::ratio<1>, (anonymous namespace)::sleep_for<long int, std::ratio<1> >(const std::chrono::duration<long int>&, const std::stop_token&)::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/11/condition_variable:435 (MyAppTest+0x2d93ef)
    #7 sleep_for<long int, std::ratio<1> > /home/def/repos/MyApp/Tests/main.cpp:21 (MyAppTest+0x2d9204)
    #8 operator() /home/def/repos/MyApp/Tests/main.cpp:32 (MyAppTest+0x2d9016)
    #9 __invoke_impl<void, main()::<lambda(std::stop_token)>, std::stop_token> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:61 (MyAppTest+0x2da0db)
    #10 __invoke<main()::<lambda(std::stop_token)>, std::stop_token> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:96 (MyAppTest+0x2d9fd2)
    #11 _M_invoke<0, 1> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:253 (MyAppTest+0x2d9ede)
    #12 operator() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:260 (MyAppTest+0x2d9e6a)
    #13 _M_run /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:211 (MyAppTest+0x2d9e20)
    #14 <null> <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xda6b3)

Thread T1 (tid=6769, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:969 (libtsan.so.0+0x605f8)
    #1 std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xda989)
    #2 _S_create<main()::<lambda(std::stop_token)> > /usr/include/c++/11/thread:217 (MyAppTest+0x2d94c0)
    #3 jthread<main()::<lambda(std::stop_token)> > /usr/include/c++/11/thread:118 (MyAppTest+0x2d9301)
    #4 main /home/def/repos/MyApp/Tests/main.cpp:33 (MyAppTest+0x2d908a)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: lock-order-inversion (potential deadlock) /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits/gthr-default.h:749 in __gthread_mutex_lock
==================
ThreadSanitizer: reported 2 warnings
```

but if I replace `sleep_for` function with this:

```
template<typename Rep, typename Period>
void sleep_for(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& d, const std::stop_token& token)
{
    std::mutex mutex;

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ mutex };

    std::condition_variable cv;

    std::stop_callback stop_wait
    {
        token,
        [&cv]()
        {
            cv.notify_one();
        }
    };

    cv.wait_for(lock, d, [&token]()
    {
        return token.stop_requested();
    });
}
```

GCC thread sanitizer stops reporting errors.

What can be the difference?

I am not sure if lambda in the first version should return `false` or `token.stop_requested()`, but the both alternatives have the same errors.

Comment: Why is `mutex` a local variable? Only one piece of code will ever lock it. And what is this code trying to do?

Comment: There should be a lot more to that sanitizer error message, which would help.

Comment: @NateEldredge uploaded full ThreadSanitizer log.

Comment: @NicolBolas I do now know what is it, I copied this from some strange website https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread/request_stop

Comment: @NicolBolas The code is pointless, it just blocks until it times out or is stopped. It probably tries to demonstrate how to use one of the types used but fails to create a realistic context. The mutex seems there just to satisfy the interface of the condition variable.

Comment: @Dmitriano maybe a false positive: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=101978 . It doesn't report anything for `wait()` with stoken (like in the cppreference example), only for `wait_for()` with stoken (like in your example). Also it doesn't report anything when compiled with clang.

Comment: @NicolBolas the code is on `request_stop()` page, so it tries to demonstrate how to stop a thread using this function together with either polling the stoken (in sleep_worker example) or waiting on stoken (in the waiting_worker example). Sure, in real life you would probably have this mutex in a bigger scope and would wait to be notified about other things too, but it doesn't seem necessary here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug in gcc (the [one](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=101978) I mentioned in the comments). When `wait_for()` is used and another thread tries to lock the same mutex then it triggers "double lock" warning. A simplified example:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;

void run1() {
    std::unique_lock lck{mtx};
    cv.wait_for(lck, 1s);
}
void run2() {
    std::unique_lock lck{mtx};
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
    cv.notify_all();
}
int main() {
    std::jthread th1{ run1 };
    std::jthread th2{ run2 };
}
```

The reason why it doesn't trigger the warning in your second version of `sleep_for()` is because in the `stop_callback` you don't try to lock the mutex before calling `cv.notify_one();`. And `std::condition_variable_any` does exactly that, see [condition_variable:404](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/std/condition_variable#L403) and [condition_variable:298](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/std/condition_variable#L298):

```cpp
// line 404:
      std::stop_callback __cb(__stoken, [this] { notify_all(); });

// lines 295-300:
    void
    notify_all() noexcept
    {
      lock_guard<mutex> __lock(*_M_mutex);
      _M_cond.notify_all();
    }
```

I believe that corresponds to the stacktrace from your warning:

```
#4 std::_V2::condition_variable_any::notify_all()
/usr/include/c++/11/condition_variable:299 (MyAppTest+0x857f6)
#5 operator()
/usr/include/c++/11/condition_variable:404 (MyAppTest+0x2d9556)
```

EDIT:

Based on [Why does C++20 std::condition_variable not support std::stop_token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66309276/why-does-c20-stdcondition-variable-not-support-stdstop-token) your second version of `sleep_for()` probably has a race condition if that lock in the `stop_callback` is missing.

So let's see, [std::condition_variable::wait_for (2)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for) says that it is equivalent to `wait_until()` and [std::condition_variable::wait_until (2)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until) says it is equivalent to:

```cpp
while (!pred()) {
    if (wait_until(lock, timeout_time) == std::cv_status::timeout) {
        return pred();
    }
}
```

Some possible scenario:

1. watchdog thread: inside `wait_until()` it gets a spurious wakeup, calls your predicate, which returns false. Before it gets a chance to call `wait_until()` again...
2. main thread: stops the watchdog thread, executes the `stop_callback`, which calls `notify_all()`...
3. watchdog thread: misses the notification because it hasn't called `wait_until()` yet. It calls it now and waits until timeout (or another spurious wakeup).

As a result, the thread doesn't stop when it should.